# basic IIS with asp.net framework 4.8 throws an error when a folder is converted to application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I wonder if someone can help me on this: when a folder is converted to application on IIS, I can't run any .aspx file inside it. If I remove the application and revert it to a normal folder, everything works fine. It's on a very complex website, but I found the issue happens also with a sample two-page website.

Very simple steps to reproduce the issue:

- Open Visual Studio 2022, create a new ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) using framework 4.8.
- Create a new "test.aspx" file on the root, and then a folder "testfolder", with a "test2.aspx" file inside of it.
- Create an IIS website, point to the root folder where the "test.aspx" file is.
- Build the project, test the page from, for example "www.mytest.com/test.aspx": it runs.
- Test also [www.mytest.com/testfolder/test2.aspx](http://www.mytest.com/testfolder/test2.aspx): it runs.
- Now, right click "testfolder" under IIS, click on "convert to application".
- /test.aspx still runs fine, but /testfolder/test2.aspx throws an error like "  Exception type: HttpParseException
  Exception message: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located.

If I remove the application from IIS (right click -> remove) and revert "testfolder" it to a simple folder, everything works fine again.

How can I fix this problem? I need a folder of my bigger website to have it's own application, because it's a high-concurrency website and I need to isolate memory allocation.

Comment: You have myfolder, and testfolder? This is confusing. When you create + add the new web site, then you already created a whole new separate application and web site. You don't have "myfolder", since that's where you pointed the new site to as root when you created it. Now, of course if you only have ONE url mapped to the one site? Then yes, you don't create a new site, but drop that WHOLE new folder into the existing site in a sub folder. So, yes, in that case then you can/should convert that sub folder into an application - but it WILL reside in one of the existing sites, not a whole new site

Comment: you're right, sorry, I edited my question: it's only one folder, "testfolder". So there's one website, made of two pages. One page at the root ("test.aspx") and one page under /testfolder/test2.aspx. If you convert the /testfolder to an application via IIS, you can't run anymore the /testfolder/test2.aspx because it throws an error. You can reproduce the bug, it takes a few minutes...

Comment: You don't want to convert testfolder to application. You already created an "application" when  you added the new web site and pointed the new site to that project folder.  You only use convert to application if that is a sub folder is part of an existing web site. Not a new one like you just created. testfolder is a sub folder of your new root project you just created. Now, if you want this to work say in one of the other already existing sites? Then you add that project folder to existing site and then set as application folder. You don't want to make the whole one web page test2.aspx a site

Comment: According to your description, I tested it, but it didn't reproduce your problem. After I convert testfolder to application, I can still access /testfolder/test2.aspx normally. You need to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Could you try assigning same Application pool to both parent and child applications.